# How to render child component with bootstrap styles applied correctly?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

My secondary Angular component is not styled properly by bootstrap `css` 
when the selector is embedded in `app.component.html`. I'm using 
ng-bootstrap by including it after a default angular8 project was 
created using `ng new myapp`

I generated a new app using the Angular CLI: `ng new my-new-app`. Then 
installed `ng-bootstrap`
In `app.component.html` I have included the directive: `app-child` and the 
component is included successfully but it isn't styled by bootstrap. 
When I dump the code directly in app.component.html (not using the 
app-child directive; it's commented out) the bootstrap styles are 
applied successfully. 
Seems that the `app-child` component with bootstrap 
styles is not rendered correctly with `bootstrap` styles applied.

Anywhere in app.component.html, include the child-components

```html
<div class="container content">
   <div class="row">
     <app-child-left></app-child-left>

     <app-child-right></app-child-right>
   </div>
</div>
```

app-child-left contains:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
   Child LEFT
</div>
```

app-child-right contains:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
   Child RIGHT
</div>
```

I expect Divs to be inserted properly and Bootstrap rendering the 
child-left, to the left and child-right, to the right.

the actual result is a large block of text on the left.
[image]

EDIT:
Here is my angular.json file.

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

This configuration works could this be a bug? Bringing div class=row into the child will cause the html and styles to render correctly:

app.component.html

```html
<div class="container content">
  <!--div class="row"-->

    <app-child-left></app-child-left>

    <!-- app-child-right></app-child-right-->

  <!-- /div -->
</div>
```

child-left.component.html:

```html
<!--div class="col-md-6">
        Child LEFT:
      </div -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Child LEFT
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Child RIGHT
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Have you imported `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` for child module? How does your `app.module` look like?

Comment: Has you add in angular.json in tag **styles** before the "src/styles.css"  a bootstrap.css or bootstrap.css.min?, see https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config. Remember that you don't need download all the bootstrap, else ONLY the bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I am assuming OP has, because OP mentioned that he was able to see styles.

Comment: @nicraft my app.module imports NgbModule as well as ChildLeftComponent and ChildRightComponent. In declarations ChildLeftComponent and ChildRightComponent is listed.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add Bootstrap 4 `CSS` to your application in order to use ngxBootstrap.

You can install using npm :  `npm i bootstrap`; and include to your `angular.json`
as below:

```
 "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
```

> you need only CSS and should not add other JavaScript dependencies
>   like bootstrap.js, jQuery or popper.js as `ng-bootstrap`'s goal is to
>   completely replace them.

Comment: @nicraft in angular.json.. under architect. styles:[ "src/styles.scss",{ "input":"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" } ]

Comment: no need for input just add `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` after styles.scss path. **Updated my answer for you**

Comment: because of reboot we need to place bootstrap first in angular.json - that order is the why it gets applied. I also made another update - this might be a bug - but when you bring the div with class=row into left child and remove it from app.component.html everything works.